# Mod rewrite redirect one file to a file on another domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have been at this for a number of hours and cannot get this to work. I have other redirects in this .htaccess file that do work.

I need to redirect as follows.

`mydomain.com/dir/subdir/myfile.php` to `myotherdomain.com/dir/my_index.php`

Note that `mydomain.com` and `myotherdomain.com` both point to the same root directory.

Here's my code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?postle.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pi_www/hardface/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pi_www/hardface/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?hardfacetechnologies.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ postle_hft/index_hft.php [L]
```

I have tired all the permutation of this I can think of and nothing works.  I really would appreciate some help.

Comment: Where is this htaccess located? Is it inside `/dir/`?

Comment: It's in the parent directory of dir which is webroot which is equivalent to mydomain.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .htaccess file in your document root, try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^dir/subdir/myfile\.php$ http://myotherdomain.com/dir/my_index.php [R=302,L]
```

The order of directives is important. This should come after your canonical `www` redirect, but before any *internal rewrites*, and before any redirects that might conflict.

This also assumes that your canonical URL is the bare domain (ie. not the www subdomain) - like with the example in your question. To match the bare domain *or* the www subdomain (and make it case-insensitive) then change the `RewriteCond` directive to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
```

Change the temporary (`302`) redirect to permanent (`301`) when you are sure it's working OK. (301 redirects are cached by the browser, so makes testing troublesome.)

Comment: I placed that code first in .hataccess and then last and it doesn't work. The old file still comes up. (Of course I emptied the cache).

Comment: Are you accessing the site via the `www` subdomain or bare domain? The code in my answer assumes the bare domain, as in your example. If you already have some working redirects then either this rule is in the wrong place and/or there is a conflict, or there is some information missing from the question. You may need to post your entire .htaccess so we can have a better look.

Comment: I did not realize your code was for a bare domain, but now that I  understand it, it's obvious. I used your code without the www and it worked fine.  I ended up using the RewriteCond from the first post with your RewriteRule so that it will work whether url contains www or not. Thanks very much for your answer. Here's the complete code for others.Perhaps you could post it as the answer.  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mydir\mysubdir\myfile\.php$ http://myotherdomain.com/dir/my_index.php [R=302,L]

Comment: Note http:// should appear just before myotherdomain.com/dir/my_index.php [R=302,L] so it is a complete url. Apparently the stackoverflow code sees it as a link and removes the http://.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If you need to retain formatting in comments (such as for a URL or code) then you can surround the text in backticks, just as you would for inline code in the question/answer text.

Comment: Just curious... where does your .htaccess code (as pasted in your question) originate? It's just that I've seen almost identical code in two other questions recently.

Answer (score 2):

You  can use this rule in **`/dir/subdir/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^myfile\.php$ http://myotherdomain.com/dir/my_index.php [R=302,NC,L]
```

If you want to avoid external redirect then:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^myfile\.php$ /dir/my_index.php [NC,L]
```

should also work as both domains point to same site root.

Comment: I placed the code first in my htaccess file and cleared the cache but the old file still comes up. I am at a loss.

Comment: As suggested in answer, did you place this in `/dir/subdir/.htaccess`?

Comment: .htaccess has to be in the root dir as there are other redirects

Comment: Are there other rules for `/dir/subdir/` URIs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The RewriteCond was correct but the RewriteRule needs the complete path as below.  RewriteRule ^mydir\mysubdir\myfile\.php$ http://myotherdomain.com/dir/my_index.php [R=302,NC,L]. You certainly know more about the code for htaccess files than I do. Of course that's not saying much... my grandmother knows more about htaccess files than me. :-) Thanks again.

Comment: You can use: `RewriteRule ^dir/subdir/myfile\.php$ http://myotherdomain.com/dir/my_index.php [R=302,NC,L]`